# Adding and subtracting strings and numbers in Javascript - auto type conversion?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

Let's look at the following Javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    function test()
    {
        alert('2'+8);
        alert(8-'2');
    }
</script>
```

---

In the first alert box, it displays the result of concatenation of 2 and 8 which is **28**. In the second alert box, however it displays the subtraction of two numbers which is **6**. How?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html, check out the example for 'concat'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `+` operator is overloaded. If any operand is a string, string concatenation is performed. If you have two numbers, addition is performed. The `-` is not overloaded in such a way and all operands are converted to numbers.

From the specification:

> [**11.6.1   The Addition operator ( + )**](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.6.1)
>
> (...)
>   7. If Type(*lprim*) is String or Type(*rprim*) is String, then
>
> - Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(*lprim*) followed by ToString(*rprim*)
>
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to ToNumber(*lprim*) and ToNumber(*rprim*).
>   (...)
>
> [**11.6.2   The Subtraction Operator ( - )**](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.6.2)
>
> (...)
>   5. Let *lnum* be ToNumber(*lval*).
>   6. Let *rnum* be ToNumber(*rval*).
>   7. Return the result of applying the subtraction operation to *lnum* and *rnum*.
>   (...)

Answer (score 5):

`+` is used for both string concatenation and addition. If either operant is a string, concatenation is used. `-` is only used for subtraction, both operants are always cast to numbers.

Answer (score 4):

`+` is used for both concatenation and addition, but when used with a string, defaults to concatenation. `-` cannot be used on strings, so its operands are converted to numbers.

Edit: This is not meant to be identical to the above post! XD

Answer (score 1):

1st: it casts 2nd operand to the 1st operand (String), because + is used for strings concat too.

2nd: it casts 2nd operand to a Number, because - is just used for numbers operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want this, an easy fix is: (1*'2')+8  JSYK